# Golang use bash environment variables in Buffalo database.yml

Tags: bash, go, buffalo

I'm new to Go and Buffalo, and am attempting use my bash environment variables in my database.yaml

I attempted to do the following in my database.yaml, but it fails to interpret the value of my bash environment var `localUser`

```
user: ${localUser}
```

I set the localUser with the following bash

```
export localUser="username"
echo $localUser
```

> username

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The data in database.yaml file IS environment variables. The app reads that file at startup. If you need to modify those values with custom logic you would do that in the app with Go code.

Comment: @BrianWagner my goals is to use the environment variables that are on my machine in the .yaml, so they are not stored in my git repo.

Comment: Ah ok good intention. I think the easy solution and one that’s fairly common is to keep the database.yaml file out of the repo. Or leave default values in there for dev or test, and overwrite locally as needed. That can be confusing to avoid accidentally committing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffalo Pop's configuration, `database.yml`, supports the following syntax.

```yaml
production:
  host: "localhost"
  user: {{ envOr "localUser" "defaultuser" }}

test:
  dialect: "mysql"
  url: {{ envOr "TEST_DATABASE_URL" "mysql://user:pass@(localhost:3306)/test" }}
```

The key is the `envOr` directive.
As you can imagine, the `production.user` will be set as the value from the environment variable `localUser` if the value exists, but it will fall back to its default value "defaultuser" if there is no environment variable.

With this syntax, you can configure environment-specific values dynamically.

This is good for many situations such as container images that could be used in multiple different configurations. You can distribute (or publish) your application "image" with the default value, then you can run your "container" with specific environmental variables with the real values.